# how to effectively build string in c?

Tags: c, string, loops

I have been working on a project to collect records from some log files and to host in database for analytical purpose where I need to deal with some million rows. For sql insertion purpose, I am trying to do batch insertion of 1000 records or more.

I created one my own function to concatenate sql queries of 1000 records.

steps

- A loop for building the string for sql insertion.
- on each 1000th of loop the sql query will be processed and freed with `free()`
- I put a `sleep(1)` on each 1000th of loop. so that I have time to check resource monitor on task manger and stop the program by pressing `ctrl+c`
- continues till the total records are processd.

Problem is,

My system has 8 GBs of memory, before running the program, memory usage is 1.8GB. below is the loop count and memory usage (aprox).

```
loop      memory usage
10,000    2.2 GB
20,000    3.6 GB
40,000    5.0 GB
```

and it continues.. when reaches 60,000+, memory usage becomes 100%.

I am afraid I am doing something wrong somewhere. I can not figure out it. How can I free up memory on each execution and keep the system stable while program ends.?

below is my full code for testing...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>


typedef struct _device_data
{       
    int uid;
    double stime;   
    double dur;
    char *location;
} DeviceData;

char *buildSQLstr(const char *sql, const DeviceData *deviceData);

int main(void)
{

    char *sql = "";
    int loop = 0;
    int sqlIsReady = 0; 

    for (loop = 0; loop<60000; loop++)
    {
        DeviceData deviceData = {};
        deviceData.stime = 343434.34343;
        deviceData.dur = 1.00343;
        deviceData.location = malloc(50);
        deviceData.location[0] = '\0';
        sprintf(deviceData.location, "Location No: - %d", loop);

        if (loop % 1000 == 0) { 
            if (sqlIsReady) {
                printf("\nLoop = %d\tLength of ssql : %d\n", loop, strlen(sql));
                free(sql);
                sql = "";
                sqlIsReady = 0;     
                sleep(1);               
            }
        }
        else {
            sql = buildSQLstr(sql, &deviceData);
            if (strlen(sql) > 0)
                sqlIsReady = 1;
        }
    }   

    printf("%d\n", strlen(sql));    
    getchar();

    return 0;
}



char *buildSQLstr(const char *sql, const DeviceData *deviceData)
{   
    char *insert_pattern = "INSERT INTO access(stime,dur,location,uid) VALUES (datetime(%f, 'unixepoch'), %f, '%s', %d);";
    int sql_size = strlen(insert_pattern) + (sizeof(double) * 2) + strlen(deviceData->location) + sizeof(int) + 1;
    char *sql_insert = malloc(sql_size);
    sql_insert[0] = '\0';
    sprintf(sql_insert, insert_pattern, deviceData->stime, deviceData->dur, deviceData->location, deviceData->uid);


    char *ptrRetSql = (char *) malloc(strlen(sql) + strlen(sql_insert) + 1);
    if (ptrRetSql != NULL) {
        ptrRetSql[0] = '\0';
        strncpy(ptrRetSql, sql, strlen(sql));
        strncat(ptrRetSql, sql_insert, strlen(sql_insert)); 
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed : %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    free(sql_insert); // here I am freeing the memory allocated for sql_insert pointer
    return ptrRetSql;
}
```

.

Please advice how can I overcome this issue..

**EDIT (Final working copy)**

Thanks guys, based on below replies, I modified my code as in below block. It is working smoothly now. My memory usage meter is stable for any number of loops now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>


typedef struct
{       
    int uid;
    double stime;   
    double dur;
    char *location;
} DeviceData_t;

char *buildSQLstr(const char *sql, const DeviceData_t *deviceData);

int main(void)
{

    char *sql = NULL;
    int loop = 0;
    int sqlIsReady = 0; 

    for (loop = 0; loop<100010; loop++)
    {
        DeviceData_t *deviceData = (DeviceData_t *) malloc(sizeof(DeviceData_t));
        deviceData->stime = 343434.34343;
        deviceData->dur = 1.00343;
        deviceData->location = (char *) malloc(50);
        if (deviceData->location != NULL) {
            deviceData->location[0] = '\0';
            sprintf(deviceData->location, "Location No: - %d", loop);
        }

        if (loop % 1000 == 0) { 
            if (sqlIsReady) {
                if (sql != NULL) free(sql);
            // Process here the sql
                sql = NULL;
                sqlIsReady = 0;     
            }
            printf("Current loop count : %d\n", loop);
        }
        else {
            char *tmpSql = buildSQLstr(sql, deviceData);            
            if (sql != NULL) free(sql);

            sql = malloc(strlen(tmpSql) + 1);
            sql[0] = '\0';      
            strcpy(sql, tmpSql);
            free(tmpSql);
            if (strlen(sql) > 0)
                sqlIsReady = 1;
        }
        if (deviceData != NULL) free(deviceData);       
    }   

    if (sql != NULL) {
        printf("%Remaining SQL Length : %d\n%s\n", strlen(sql), sql);   
        free(sql);
    }

    return 0;
}



char *buildSQLstr(const char *sql, const DeviceData_t *deviceData)
{       
    char *insert_pattern = "INSERT INTO access(stime,dur,location,uid) VALUES (datetime(%f, 'unixepoch'), %f, '%s', %d);";
    int sql_size = strlen(insert_pattern) + (sizeof(double) * 2) + strlen(deviceData->location) + sizeof(int) + 1;
    char *sql_insert = (char *) malloc(sql_size);
    sql_insert[0] = '\0';
    sprintf(sql_insert, insert_pattern, deviceData->stime, deviceData->dur, deviceData->location, deviceData->uid);

    int ptrRetSql_size;
    if (sql != NULL ) ptrRetSql_size = strlen(sql) + strlen(sql_insert) + 1;
    else ptrRetSql_size = strlen(sql_insert) + 1;

    char *ptrRetSql = (char *) malloc(ptrRetSql_size);

    if (ptrRetSql != NULL) {        
        ptrRetSql[0] = '\0';        
        if (sql != NULL) strcat(ptrRetSql, sql);

        if (sql != NULL) strcat(ptrRetSql, sql_insert); 
        else strcpy(ptrRetSql, sql_insert);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed : %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    if (sql_insert != NULL) free(sql_insert);
    return ptrRetSql;
}
```

And another question arise here. Should I individuality clean the memory allocated by `deviceData->location` ?

Comment: `sprintf`? `strncat`? Really?

Comment: `sprintf` is used to pass the values to sql query. `strncat` is used to concatenate the old and new sql statements.

Comment: @BlueBird: Aside from the actual leak, type mismatches and poor code all over. Why setting the first character to `\0` if the next operation is writing to that location? What's with all those magic numbers? What's with `DeviceData` vs. `_device_data` vs. `deviceData`? Don't cast `malloc()`'s return value. Const correctness. Compiler warnings! `strncat`'ing two strings together, but passing only the length of one string as third parameter, potentially leaving you with a non-null-terminated result. And and and... you need to strive for more precise coding, or you'll keep running into problems.

Comment: @DevSolar, thanks for your points. I think setting the first character is must to make a null character. I can see it in below reply of `dasblinkenlight` also. If it is wrong, please explain me whether I should leave it or assign null character in different way?

Comment: @DevSolar `_device_data` is struct's name, 'DeviceData` is defined type name and `deviceData` is variable name which I am creating out of the type.. what's wrong here. please explain.

Comment: @BlueBird I'm sure blinken just copied your code without scrutinizing every line because he was making a different point. Dev is right, it doesn't make sense. Much of your code is funny, e.g. initializing a char* with "". The usual way is to use NULL which is the usual indicator for "not initialized" and is safe to "delete" in standard conforming implementations of both C and C++ (the delete would do nothing, while a delete on "" usually barfs).

Comment: @BlueBird: One, if you're `typedef`'ing a struct in the first line, keep it anonymous, since you're not going to use `struct _device_data` anyway. Two, use the `_t` suffix to indicate a type (like `size_t` or `uint32_t`). Try to use something else than the type name for the variable identifier. Just imagine yourself talking about your code to another developer. You say "device data". What are you referring to, the type or the variable? I.e., "device data t" vs. "device", and your communication becomes much clearer.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. and pls tell me what you mean about ///"Why setting the first character to \0 if the next operation is writing to that location?"///

Comment: @BlueBird: You're setting the string to "empty", and with the very next statement, you're filling it. `location[0] = '\0'` is effectively a no-op. Fluff. Unnecessary.

Comment: @DevSolar No. In which line you are talking about. I am setting in 3 places where I am using `malloc()`. (1) for `deviceData.location[0] = '\0';` (2) for `sql_insert[0] = '\0';` in `buildSQLstr()` function (3) for `ptrRetSql[0] = '\0';` in same function. All these 3 are right after `malloc()`. You are pointing them or else?

Comment: @BlueBird: All three of them are immediately followed by filling the memory in question with a string operation, making all three lines superfluous. But this is only a minor issue, contributing to the overall impression of "damn, this is awkward".

Comment: @BlueBird: This is the wrong approach; you *don't* want to use SQL `insert` statements for bulk loads.  Even if you fix all your code issues, the operation will be *excrutiatingly* slow.  Most database engines that I know of support a bulk data import from delimited text files; check the documentation for your database engine.

Comment: @DevSolar actually I am new to c. It is only 2 weeks since I started programming in c. I am a pure PHP and C# programmer. Your comments worth to me. I want to know where I can improve in my coding. Can you just modify the above code in a standard manner and post it for me? So that I can grasp a good idea of it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at http://hg.pdclib.e43.eu/pdclib/src. It's an implementation of the C standard library, so its contents might be just as educational as its style. Owen did a terrific job continuing the project when I dropped it, but the early stuff (string, stdlib, stdio) is mine.

Comment: Thanks @DevSolar . Also please look at my update now. I added a final working copy of updated code. Are you still seeing funny things on it? please point me out them.

Comment: Part of me would love to do it. The other part of me knows that a proper code review would need something like a Skype connection and proper preparation, and I've already invested much more time in this question than I ususally do on SO. This is my day job, you understand? All the best with your learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code `malloc`s the return value of `buildSQLstr` function (13-th line from the bottom) and then returns the string to `main`. However, neither `main` nor `buildSQLstr` frees that string until the iteration divisible by 1000, creating memory leaks on the remaining 999 iterations.

Since the old value of `sql` passed to `buildSQLstr` becomes irrelevant after `strcat`, you can `free` the old string right there:

```
if (ptrRetSql != NULL) {
    ptrRetSql[0] = '\0';
    strncpy(ptrRetSql, sql, strlen(sql));
    free(sql); // <<==== Here
    strncat(ptrRetSql, sql_insert, strlen(sql_insert)); 
}
```

You also need to `free` the final value of `sql` inside the `main` to avoid leaking the last `sql` string. In order to do that correctly you should change the declaration to

```
char *sql = malloc(1);
sql[0] = '\0';
```

Otherwise, you risk passing a pointer to the `""` string literal to `free` when the log is empty, causing undefined behavior. Same goes for the assignment of `""` in the top branch of the `if`, when you do free it.

Comment: I wouldn't call free on a pointer arg inside a function. It could (a) be non-dynamic (as it is in the OP's code -- the function can't know who's calling it!), or (b) the caller may try to use it later. Both is disastrous. Generally, the responsibility for deleting is with the creating code.

Comment: @PeterSchneider "the responsibility for deleting is with the creating code." - That's the reasoning why I put it in `buildSQLstr`, because ultimately that's where it has been allocated. There are multiple solutions to this problem, though, the simplest one being a switch to C++ with its dynamic strings.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: +1. I believe you need a good reason to *not* use C++ instead of C today, even if you use none of the C++ features except `<vector>` and `<string>`...

Comment: How to free the function returned char* that is of malloc?

Comment: @BlueBird Add `free(sql)` after the end of the loop.

Comment: It is giving me error. Segment fault. I will post the updated code according to your reply.

Answer (score 3):

You are freeing sql which was never malloc'ed; and you are never freeing deviceData.location, which *is* malloc'ed. The latter is your memory problem. The former is your crash problem, on Friday 13.

Comment: Yes. It is also a correct point, but regarding `devicedata.location`.. it is not much causing the issue. I returned some small value from function `buildSQLstr()` instead of generating the real sql and tested. It run over million queris while `deviceData.location` as it is. .

Comment: @BlueBird: You could simply define an array with 50 chars inside the device_data struct. I understand it's "throwaway data" which is just sprintf'ed, i.e. copied into the sql_insert. No need to allocate dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are only freeing the memory each 1000th iteration. You are passing sql into buildSQLstr which allocates a new bufffer and returns it, but the original sql is not freed.

Try something like:

```
   else {
        char * tmpPtr =buildSQLstr(sql, &deviceData);
        free(sql);
        sql = tmpPtr;
        if (strlen(sql) > 0)
            sqlIsReady = 1;
    }
```

Alternatively, realloc sql inside buildSQLstr.

If you know how big the buffer can get, it may be more efficient to just allocate the buffer once with it's maximum size, rather than allocating and freeing it each time.